# PHP - preg_replace_callback function

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have a `preg_replace_callback` function and when i open my webpage, i get the following warning:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2,
>   'stripslashes(strstr("\2\5","rel=\class=") ? "\1" :

This is my function:

```
function ace_colorbox_replace($string) {

     $pattern = '/(<a(.*?)href="([^"]*.)'.IMAGE_FILETYPE.'"(.*?)><img)/ie';

     $result = 'stripslashes(strstr("\2\5","rel=\class=") ? "\1" : "<a\2href=\"\3\4\"\5 rel=\"colorbox\" class=\"colorbox\"><img")';

     return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $string);

}
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks
Br Robert

Comment: The second argument of `preg_replace_callack` must be a function, not a variable.

Comment: Thanks and how would you write the whole function then?

Comment: Replace `$callback` by `function($m) { body of the function here }`. See the doc for examples

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote is not complete

in `preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $string);` you have `$pattern` defined all right but `$callback` variable is not defined

You have to define it or use a constant

Also you have the `$result` variable which is not used so it's unnecessary

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes sry, this was a copying mistake

```
function ace_colorbox_replace($string) {
  $pattern = '/(<a(.*?)href="([^"]*.)'.IMAGE_FILETYPE.'"(.*?)><img)/ie';
  $callback = 'stripslashes(strstr("\2\5","rel=\class=") ? "\1" : "<a\2href=\"\3\4\"\5 rel=\"colorbox\" class=\"colorbox\"><img")';
  return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $string);
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your question if you want to add some info.